# Accounting settings cannot be changed in Odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I need to modify an option of the accounting configuration (menu *Accounting > Configuration > Accounting*).

As you know, those options belong to a Transient Model named `account.config.settings`, which inherits from `res.config.settings`.

The problem is that even if I modify no option and click on *Apply*, Odoo begins loading forever. I put the log in `debug_sql` mode, and I realised that after clicking on *Apply*, Odoo starts to make thousands of SQL queries, and that is the reason why it does not stop loading.

I made a database backup and restored it in a newer instance of Odoo 8. In this instance, when I click on *Apply*, Odoo makes several SQL queries but not so much as in the other instance, so it works perfectly.

My conclusion was that the problem could be in the instance code (not in the database), so I looked for all the modules inheriting from `account.config.settings` and updated their repositories to go back to the same commits as the wrong instance (with `git checkout xxx`).

Afterwards I was expecting the newer instance to start failing when clicking on *Apply*, but it remains working OK.

So I am running out of ideas. I am thinking about running the backup database in the newer instance just to change the option I need, and after that restoring it again in the older instance, but I prefer to avoid that since I think it is a bit risky.

Any ideas? What more can I try to find out the problem?

Comment: Does both the instance have same base code or it changes are there ?

Comment: Even the base code is different in both. I did the other way round, updated all the repositories of the old instance to the newest version, and the error disappeared. So now, I am doing the same process again, this time repository by repository, to check which is the guilty one. After finding it out, I would analyse each one of its modules. A tough task.

Comment: So that might be possible that other repos are also affecting this situation.

Comment: If updating Odoo 8 to newer code isn't possible (and i know enough arguments for it), try to find the problem and fix it yourself. Maybe there was a Commit on `account.config.settings` which solved the problem. There were some "strange" fixes in Odoo 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the guilty module. It was `account_due_list` from the repository `account-payment` of the Odoo Community Association. The commit which fixes the problem is https://github.com/OCA/account-payment/commit/d7a09399982c80bb0f9465c44b9dc2a2b17e557a#diff-57131fd364915a56cbf8696d74e19478, merged on September the 22nd in 2016. Its title, "*check if currency id not changed per company, remove it from create values*".

The computed field `maturity_residual` depended on `company_id.currency_id`. This dependency has to be removed due to be the cause of the whole problem. It triggered thousands of SQL queries which made Odoo be loading forever.

**Old and wrong code**

```
@api.depends('date_maturity', 'debit', 'credit', 'reconcile_id',
             'reconcile_partial_id', 'account_id.reconcile',
             'amount_currency', 'reconcile_partial_id.line_partial_ids',
             'currency_id', 'company_id.currency_id')
             'currency_id')
def _maturity_residual(self):
   ...
```

**New and right code**

```
@api.depends('date_maturity', 'debit', 'credit', 'reconcile_id',
             'reconcile_partial_id', 'account_id.reconcile',
             'amount_currency', 'reconcile_partial_id.line_partial_ids',
             'currency_id')
def _maturity_residual(self):
   ...
```

I found very risky to update repositories to the latest version due to what @CZoellner exactly says, sometimes there are weird commits which can destroy some database data. So, these are the consequences of not doing that.